# Scaling images in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I am using `ImageViewBuilder` to create an `ImageView` and I need to test the properties `preserveRatio` , `fitWidth` and `fitheight`

I was looking at the docs **and still cannot figure out how to.**
Help will be appreciated. Here is my code (not SSCCE)

```
ImageView img = ImageViewBuilder
                .create()
                .image(new Image("http://projavafx.com/images/earthrise.jpg")) // path to image
                .build();
```

If someone could please update the code to show me how to use the `fitHeight()` and `fitWidth()` methods then that would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IT is not entirely clear what you are trying to do.  To use the fitWidth/fitHeight/preserveRatio properties, you can either use the get/set.. methods or,

```
ImageView img = ImageViewBuilder
            .create()
            .image(new Image("http://projavafx.com/images/earthrise.jpg")) // path to image
            .build(); 

img.setFitHeight(value); // or getFitHeight() if that is what you need.
img.setFitWidth(value);  // or getFitWidth() if that is what you need.
img.preserveRatioProperty(true);  // or isPreserveRation() if that is what you need.
```

or  alternatively, access the properties and then call the get/set methods on those:

```
img.fitHeightProperty().set(value);
img.fitWidthProperty().set(value);
img.preserveRatioProperty().set(true);
```

This is pretty basic. If you put more information about what exactly the problem is, then you might get a more specific and less basic answer.

- chooks

Comment: The problem is the value of 'value'. Where are the constants like 'preserveRatio' stored ?

Comment: the 'value' in my example is a placeholder for whatever you are trying to set the fitHeight/width/ratio to.  If you want to see what these values are, then use the get form (as in the example above). E.g. img.getFitHeight(), getFitWidth(), or isPreserveRatio().  

The fitHeight, width, and preserveRatio are not constants. They are properties, and as such they can be accessed like any normal property with direct getters and settings (see the first example) or through their property objects (see second example).